# How to get value of an string from another Form C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cefsharp

When i call string from another form the string is an empty string.

```
(Messenger) Form 2:
Facebook mainlist = new Facebook();
if (!(iurl == mainlist.currentstring))
{
iurl = mainlist.currestring; //Update the string
MessageBox.Show("success!");
}

(Facebook) Form 1:
public string currentstring{ get; set; }
```

Information :

I'm working with CEF3, In my Form 1 my app get the current url automatically

```
    private void OnBrowserAddressChanged(object sender, AddressChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        currenturl.Text = args.Address;
        thistring = args.Address;
    }
```

When an certain text of currenturl has been changed this open a new Form (Messenger)

```
        currenturl.TextChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            currentinbox = currenturl.Text;
            MessageBox.Show(currentinbox + " = " + currenturl.Text);
            if ((currenturl.Text.Contains("https://www.messenger.com/t/") == true) & (currenturl.Text.Contains("https://www.messenger.com/t/me/") == false))
            {

                Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("Facebook");
                if (!(pname.Length == 3))
                {
                    Messenger inbox = new Messenger();
                    inbox.iurl = currenturl.Text;
                    inbox.Show();
                    browser.Back();
                }
            }
        };
```

Then in my Form2 (Messenger) is enabled automatically an Timer.

```
    private void DetectUrl_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Facebook mainlist = new Facebook();
        if (!(iurl == mainlist.currentinbox))
        {
            string inboxme = "var els = document.getElementsByTagName(\"a\");" +
            "for (var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {" +
            "var el = els[i];" +
            "if (el.href === \"https://www.messenger.com/t/\"" + mainlist.currentinbox + "\") {" + 
            "el.click();" +
            "}" +
            "}";
            iurl = mainlist.currentinbox;
            MessageBox.Show(iurl + " = " + mainlist.currentinbox);
            browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(inboxme);
        }
    }
```

But "mainlist.currentinbox" is null or an empty string

Comment: We will need more information, in your example above when newing up the Form1 object, you don't initialize thistring anywhere before accessing thistring variable

Comment: Form1 frm1 = new Form1(); will set thistring to null :D

Comment: @NinoMirzaMušić How prevent the null string? without using "new Form1();"

Comment: I use Properties.Settings.Default.currenturl for get the current value.. 
THIS ASK IS CLOSED.

Answer (score 0):

Form1:

```
    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 n = new Form2();
        label1.Text = n.lol;
    }
```

Form2:

```
    public string lol = "xd";
```

It works currently? Maybe you did not assign anything to the thistring variable in your example?

Comment: If my string is empty and is needs to be empty because the information string that is obtained is by another event of a browser.

anyway thanks